# FileSystemWatcher doesnt detect files moved into directory using 'mv' command or cut and paste on ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

I am using a FileSystemWatcher to detect files that are dropped into a directory and then they get forwarded elsewhere and removed from directory. During devellopment I just copied files into the dir for testing, however I am just realizing that no events get fired in qa because the files are moved, not copied into the dir. Is there any way I can capture files moved into a directory using c# dotnet core on ubuntu?

Below is an excerpt of my code showing how I set up the watcher, in my actual app I was only watching the changed event, but added more event listeners to try and figure out how to do this

```
    CaptureServerSettings appSettings = provider.GetRequiredService<CaptureServerSettings>();

    using (FileSystemWatcher directoryWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(appSettings.WatchDirectory, "*.*"))
    {
        directoryWatcher.BeginInit();
        directoryWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        directoryWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        directoryWatcher.Error += errorEvent;
        directoryWatcher.Renamed += renameEvent;
        directoryWatcher.Created += createdEvent;
        directoryWatcher.Changed += changedEvent;
        directoryWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        directoryWatcher.EndInit();
        provider.GetRequiredService<CancellationTokenSource>().Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }

    private static void changedEvent(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) => _logger.LogWarning("Changed: {@eventargs}", e);

    private static void errorEvent(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) => _logger.LogWarning("Error: {@eventargs}", e);

    private static void createdEvent(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) => _logger.LogWarning("Created: {@eventargs}", e);

    private static void renameEvent(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e) => _logger.LogWarning("Renamed: {@eventargs}", e);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have figured this out without posting to stack...
My issue was two things. I need to change the NotifyFilter to include FileName changes and to subscribe to the changed event as shown below.

```
       CaptureServerSettings appSettings = provider.GetRequiredService<CaptureServerSettings>();
       using (FileSystemWatcher directoryWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(appSettings.WatchDirectory, "*.*"))
       {
            directoryWatcher.BeginInit();
            directoryWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            directoryWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
            directoryWatcher.Created += createdEvent;
            directoryWatcher.Changed += changedEvent;
            directoryWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            directoryWatcher.EndInit();
            provider.GetRequiredService<CancellationTokenSource>().Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
```